# Peculiar Map/Reduce result from CouchDB

Tags: nosql, couchdb, mapreduce

I have been using CouchDB for quite sometime without any issues. That is up until now. I recently saw something in my map/reduce results which I had overlooked!

This is before performing a `sum` on the "avgs" variable. I'm basically trying to find the average of all values pertaining to a particular key. Nothing fancy. The result is as expected.

Note the result for timestamp 1308474660000 (4th row in the table):
[image: Before summing avgs]

---

Now I `sum` the "avgs" array. Now here is something that is peculiar about the result. The sum for the key with timestamp 1308474660000 is a `null`!! Why is CouchDB spitting out `null`s for a simple `sum`? I tried with a custom addition function and its the same problem.

[image]
Can someone explain to me why is there this issue with my map/reduce result?

CouchDB version: 1.0.1

---

**UPDATE:**

After doing a rereduce I get a reduce overflow error!

```
Error: reduce_overflow_error

Reduce output must shrink more rapidly: Current output: '["001,1,1,1,1,1,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,11,1,1,1,1,1,101,1,1,1,1,1,1,11,1,1,1,1'... (first 100 of 396 bytes)
```

This is my modified reduce function:

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
  if(!rereduce) {
    var avgs = [];
    for(var i=values.length-1; i>=0 ; i--) {
      avgs.push(Number(values[i][0])/Number(values[i][1]));
    }
    return avgs;
  } else {
    return sum(values);
  };
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Well now it has gotten worse. Its selectively rereducing. Also, the ones it has rereduced show wrong results. The length of the value in 4th row for timestamp (1308474660000) should be 2 and not 3.

[image]

**UPDATE 3:**

I finally got it to work. I hadn't understood the specifics of rereduce properly. AFAIK, Couchdb itself decides how to/when to rereduce. In this example, whenever the array was long enough to process, Couchdb would send it to rereduce. So I basically had to `sum` twice. Once in reduce, and again in rereduce.

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
  if(!rereduce) {
    var avgs = [];
    for(var i=values.length-1; i>=0 ; i--) {
      avgs.push(Number(values[i][0])/Number(values[i][1]));
    }
    return sum(avgs);
  } else {
    return sum(values); //If my understanding of rereduce is correct, it only receives only the avgs that are large enough to not be processed by reduce.
  }
}
```

Comment: Follow up: I tried the same with CouchBase/Bigcouch and it calculates `sum` for the timestamp correctly but shows `null`s for other keys. Weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop in the reduce function is probably not doing what you think it is. For example, it might be throwing an exception that you did not expect.

You are expecting an array of 2-tuples:

```
// Expectation
values = [ [value1, total1]
         , [value2, total2]
         , [value3, total3]
         ];
```

During a re-reduce, the function will get old results from itself before.

```
// Re-reduce values
values = [ avg1
         , avg2
         , avg3
         ]
```

Therefore I would begin by examining how your code works if and when `rereduce` is true. Perhaps something simple will fix it (although often I have to `log()` things until I find the problem.)

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  if(rereduce)
     return sum(values);

  // ... then the same code as before.
}
```

Comment: @jhs: Thanks for the solution. Waited quite sometime for someone to reply to this. I'll try it and reply back. However, can you explain how you `log()` in couch? I though there was no way to `log`/`console.log`. This will make things easier for me. Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: I think your problem is solved. The next error is unrelated. (Reduce must *reduce* the amount of data, not simply convert it to a different format, an array.)

Comment: Also, is that possibly a string mixed in your data? It looks like maybe the string `"001"` triggered concatenation instead of number addition.

Comment: No string. I'm sure of that. Plus I'm casting the result as an added precaution. See Fig 1. `Number(values[i][0])`. As of now, I'm not doing a rereduce. I just send the array to the client and the client computes the average. So if it is working on the client end, it should work in CouchDB too right?

Comment: Ok. The question's update doesn't show that I'm casting the value and the total. I'm however doing it in the reduce view. Infact, if I just return the `values` instead of returning a `sum` I get a `null` for the array itself. So Couchdb for some weird reason is passing `null` instead of the array to rereduce.

Comment: Do you think there is some weird bug in CouchDB that needs to be reported? I'm saying so because, without a rereduce, the result of map/reduce lists the arrays correctly. However, upon rereduce, some arrays disappear entirely and get substituted by `null`.

Comment: Awesome! I got it to work. I have now understood the specifics of when rereduce comes into play. Does Couchdb itself decide when to rereduce? If so, the its a really nice feature. Unfortunately I haven't come across many articles that deal with the functionality of rereduce itself. I have updated my question. Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: Interesting. Map/reduce in CouchDB can be quite frustrating. I suggest that you solve one problem at a time, since they are conflating each other. Returning an array in reduce is not allowed. Once you solve the `reduce_overflow_error` that will help.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your last comment. Yes, CouchDB decides whether to rereduce. Anyway, the standard method to calculate the average of many values is not to compute the average, but instead to store the count and also the sum. The client can calculate the average by dividing.

Comment: Yep Map/reduce is frustrating. However, the `rereduce` functionality itself opens up new possibilities provided I have understood it correctly. Gist: if processing in reduce takes longer than necessary it is passed to rereduce. Am i correct in this assumption?

Comment: Exactly. That was what I was doing anyways (sending the result to client to calculate avg). However, this will be helpful in a lot of places. Need some refactoring in my other views now :)

Answer (score 1):

I will elaborate on my count/sum comment, just in case you are curious.

This code is not tested, but hopefully you will get the idea. The end result is always a simple object `{"count":C, "sum":S}` and you know the average by computing `S / C`.

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
  // Reduce function
  var count = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  var i;

  if(!rereduce) {
    // `values` stores actual map output
    for(i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      count += Number(values[i][1]);
      sum += Number(values[i][0]);
    }

    return {"count":count, "sum":sum};
  }

  else {
    // `values` stores count/sum objects returned previously.
    for(i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      count += values[i].count;
      sum   += values[i].sum;
    }

    return {"count":count, "sum":sum};
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! This is nice. Works for most cases. However, in my case, i'm storing precomputed value and count and would just need to find the average. So I do the same, but for average. To elaborate: for a particular timestamp I have a value/count for the key computed via redis (in some cases mongodb.. depends on the kind of data). I then store it into couchdb for reporting/charting. :) Use map/reduce to just calculate the average (value/count)

Comment: Cool. I figured you had a pesky real-world requirement :)

Answer (score -1):

I use the following code to do average. Hope it helps.

```
function (key, values) {
    return sum(values)/values.length;    
}
```